# На чём писать быстрый бекенд (go, nodejs + redis)?

Tags: node.js, golang, redis

У меня есть проект который должен обрабатывать очень много запросов, никакой сложной логики, сходить в базу отдать данные на клиент.
Я думаю использовать для этой задачи 
go либо nodeJS + redis + mysql. Насколько такой бекенд будет быстрым, понятно что медленнее чем скажем отдача статики nginx.

Я правильно понимаю что узкое место здесь будет как раз база и кеш, если да то выбор языка особого значения не сыграет?
Что можете посоветовать в данном случае?

Comment: очень много запросов это сколько ?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще отдача файлов намного проста, для сервера веб приложений.
https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r15&hw=ph&test=json

Если сравнить отдачу просто данных и данных из бд.
То там в несколько раз разница!

Все зависит от архитектуры приложения и Используемой БД!
Слишком расплывчатый вопрос!

Основная проблема будет связана с архитектурой, то как вы разгрузите БД
Лучше использовать партицинирование или кластерный подход к БД!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJ_qeogG_fg

Опишите вопрос лучше !

Comment: Redis может понадобиться, если идет работа с часто используемыми данными в качестве кеша!
Индексы БД также должны быть хорошо спроектированы, нужна конкретика!

Comment: Да данные будут часто используемыми, фактически база тут нужна в качестве постоянного хранилища на диске. Запрос за одними и теми же данными в базу будет повторяться очень редко. Основную работу будет делать кеш

Comment: Весь кейс это забрать данные из базы, записать в кеш и раздать клиентам. База mysql кеш редис, бекенд не написан. Хочу написать простой сервер на Go или NodeJs

Comment: Лучше сразу использовать golang! Google хорошо постарались создавая сие чудо! Nodejs как был комунити детищем так им останется!

Comment: Лучше использовать postgresql! Или ту базу которую вы хорошо умеете оптимизировать! Именно ту с которой часто работали ! И главное никаких блобов с СУБД! После покупки mysql и форка mariadb есть сомнения в том на чем лучше работать ! У постгре вроде есть тренд стать мейнстримом! Да и в enterprise система java часто используют совместно с porstgre! А пхп с mysql! Так уж исторически сложилось !